# Adding [Authorize] to controller failing to redirect to Identity Login route. ASP.NET CORE 3.1 MVC

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-core-identity, asp.net-core-routing

I have a asp.net core 3.1 MVC project. It has Identity added to it. When I normally click a button to go to login page or registration page, it works as expected. However the moment I am using **[Authorize]** on controller or global authorization filter in *Startup.cs* file, the page does not redirect to the login page.

The redirection link in that case is

> https://localhost:5001/Account/Login?ReturnUrl=%2F

where as the link should be

> https://localhost:5001/Identity/Account/Login?ReturnUrl=%2F

If you look closely the area name **"Identity"** is missing from the link that I am getting. I am gussing there is something wrong with my *Startup.cs* file configuration but cannot figure out what.
I have **Multiple Areas** in my project along  with **Identity**

Startup.cs

```
public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        Configuration = configuration;
    }

    public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
            options.UseSqlServer(
                Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));
        /*services.AddDefaultIdentity<IdentityUser>(options => options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedAccount = true)
            .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>();*/

        services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, IdentityRole>().AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>().AddDefaultTokenProviders();
        services.AddTransient<IEmailSender, EmailSender>();
        services.AddControllersWithViews();
        services.AddRazorPages().AddMvcOptions(options => options.Filters.Add(new AuthorizeFilter()));
        services.AddSingleton<IConfiguration>(Configuration);
        services.AddMvc(options => options.EnableEndpointRouting = false);
        services.AddMvc().AddRazorRuntimeCompilation();
    }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            app.UseDatabaseErrorPage();
        }
        else
        {
            app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
            // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
            app.UseHsts();
        }

        app.UseHttpsRedirection();
        app.UseStaticFiles();

        app.UseRouting();

        app.UseAuthentication();
        app.UseAuthorization();

        app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        {

            endpoints.MapRazorPages().RequireAuthorization();
            endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
               name: "Identity",
               pattern: "{area:exists}/{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");

            endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
                name: "default",
                pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
            endpoints.MapRazorPages();
        });
    }
}
```

Any help would be much appreciate. thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Define the login path in `services.ConfigureApplicationCookie` like this:

```
services.ConfigureApplicationCookie(options =>
{
    options.LoginPath = new PathString("/Identity/Account/Login");
    //other properties
});
```

Comment: @Mill3r You're welcome! and just a reminder `ConfigureApplicationCookie` can also set your `LogoutPath` and `AccessDenied` path, you might find them useful.

Answer (score 2):

I just had a look around on GitHub and found `Account/Login` being set as a default in [CookieAuthenticationDefaults](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/master/src/Security/Authentication/Cookies/src/CookieAuthenticationDefaults.cs). I then found that being used by [PostConfigureCookieAuthenticationOptions](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/ce16ff0a51a74811674228835696e5cc78494fd7/src/Security/Authentication/Cookies/src/PostConfigureCookieAuthenticationOptions.cs), which sets sensible configuration options when none have been specified. From that, it looks to me like you have to configure that like this:

```
services.ConfigureApplicationCookie(x => x.LoginPath = "/identity/account/login");
```

`x` in this case is of type `CookieAuthenticationOptions`, which is what `PostConfigureCookieAuthenticationOptions` is reading from.

Comment: Ok, I'm too slow. :)